# Vars Saved to config.env Missing from Cypress.env()

Tags: node.js, cypress

I have an `.env` file I pull sensitive creds from, that are then placed into the browser context for Cypress.  I'm logging the values from the `config.env` right before I `return config` in the `index.js` file, and I see my added key/values.  But when I `cy.log(Cypress.env())` in the browser, they are missing.

index.js:

```
config.env.jwtSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
config.env.login = process.env.LOGIN;
```

Output from `console.log()`:

```
CONFIG {
  apiUrl: 'https://apiUrl',
  adminApiUrl: 'https://adminUrl',
  sshTunnel: { host: 'hostName' },
  db: { port: 5555 },
  jwtSecret: 'secret',
  login: 'userLogin'
}
```

Output from `cy.log()`:

```
CONFIG {
  apiUrl: 'https://apiUrl',
  adminApiUrl: 'https://adminUrl',
  sshTunnel: { host: 'hostName' },
  db: { port: 5555 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to packaged node version.  Cypress is currently on 12.8.3.  nvm'd over to 14, and problem went away.